# Function that modifys object its being called on though parent not name

Tags: javascript

I'd like to have one function that I can call to modify the text colour of the object (Textarea) that its being called on.

Instead of making 5 functions that have the name of the object its changing in each separate function.

For example

```
textarea1.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
    selectTextAreaWithioutName.style.color = red
});
```

So where it says `selectTextAreaWithioutName` id like it to grab `textarea1` even if its called `textarea2` or `textarea3` etc. without the name being explicitly stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right you can use [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to grab the element.

For example:

```
textarea1.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    event.target.style.color = red; // event.target is equal to textarea1
});
```